MapStruct Dependency Injection Issue
I can't inject dependency in mapper, what's wrong?
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = { UserMapperHelper.class })
public interface ReminderCreateMapper {
    @Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(source = "userId", target = "user")
    Reminder reminderCreateDtoToReminder(ReminderCreateDto dto);
}

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {UserService.class})
public interface UserMapperHelper {
     User toEntity(Long userId);
}

@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    public User findById(Long id) {
        return userRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException());
    }
}


But
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "ru.lebedev.reminder.mapper.UserMapperHelper.toEntity(java.lang.Long)" because "this.userMapperHelper" is null
I tried to use mapstruct map an id to an object
but it does't work.

Why do you have uses = {UserService.class}? What do you want to achieve with that?

i change on uses = {UserServiceImpl.class} but it's also does work

How are you getting an instance of ReminderCreateMapper

Have you checked the folder target/generated-sources/annotations ? Here you should fine the implementation of the mappers
